# Hiding UIButton as IBAction

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

It's not difficult to hide a UIButton typically, but I have it set to an IBAction instead of IBOutlet. This is necessary because when the button is pressed, text pops up, but then I want the button to disappear. What is the solution?

Comment: When you say "text pops up" do you mean an alert (UIAlertView) ?

Comment: I mean I have a label that is set to a certain message when the button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably declared your IBAction like:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonAction;
```

It should be:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender;
```

Because then you can do in the method

```
- (IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    if([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(setHidden:)])
        [sender setHidden:YES];
}
```

All IBActions can support receiving their sender as a function. However, if a different UI element calls that function, it too will be hidden. Also, with the method above you'll be unable to un-hide the button, and if you need to do that, you'd probably be better off having an IBOutlet - in 5.0+ you can use the `weak` keyword which does not retain a reference and is automatically nilled if the object is destroyed, and in 4.x you'll just have to remember to set it to nil on viewDidUnload.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly! Now I have another question: Before the button is pressed I have some buttons that I want hidden, but after the button is pressed I want the others to become visible. I believe I can handle the second part, but I'm not sure how to have buttons originally set to hidden.

Comment: You should really look into creating properties for this, IBOutlets for each UILabel's you want to handle. You can use a BOOL iVar a a flag so you know what state your app is in. And use the properties to update their values/hide/show whatever accordingly

Comment: Well, I only have one UILabel, which I am having no problems with, it's just that I'm not sure how to go about having certain buttons hidden when the screen first loads